# getURL doesn't return a promise object

Tags: javascript

getURL do return a promise object, why does not work?

```
const fs = require('fs');

function getURL(URL){
    fs.readFile(URL,(err, buffer)=>{
        if(err) return Promise.reject(err.message);
        return Promise.resolve(buffer.toString());
    });
    // return Promise.resolve(42); works
}
getURL('1.txt').then(text=>{
    console.log(text);
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
});
```

Thanks. Can I use static method Promise.resolve other than return new Promise object?

Comment: Your `getURL()` function does not return anything.

Comment: There is no use of returning from inside a callback function.

Comment: @NidhinDavid So the problem is async operation?

Comment: The problem is returning a value from the callback of an async function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't [return a value from an asynchronous callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321).

Instead, you need to create the promise in the outer function (with `new Promise`), and run your asynchronous code inside the executor of that promise:

```
function getURL(URL) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // run asynchronous code here
    // call resolve on success or reject on error

    fs.readFile(URL, (err, buffer) => {
      if(err)
        reject(err);
      else
        resolve(buffer.toString());
    });
  }
}
```

---

That being said, it's considered best to avoid creating promises yourself whenever you can (as [aaaaaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984407/aaaaaa) pointed out, it is a [promise antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984407/aaaaaa)). In the specific case of `fs` (and other built-in Node modules) I'd recommend that you instead use something like [`mz`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mz), which wraps all built-in modules and makes them use promises instead of callbacks:

```
const fs = require('mz/fs');
function getURL(URL) {
  return fs.readFile(URL)
    .then((buffer) => buffer.toString());
}

// or even better:
function getURL(URL) {
  return fs.readFile(URL, 'utf8');
}
```